# Show page failing to pass seed data along (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, controller, rails-activerecord, seeding

I have a seed database that renders Admin user information and links to individual member profile pages. The database renders images and data fine in the main page, but comes up nil `<p>, with id </p> *== $0*` when I try to call the individual objects on the show page.

routes.rb:

```
get '/team', to: 'pages#team'
get '/team/:id', to: 'pages#show', as: 'agent'
```

pages_controller.rb:

```
 def team
    @admins = Admin.where(role: :staff)
  end

  def show
    @admin = Admin.find(params[:id])
  end
```

views/pages/team.html.erb:

```
 <%= link_to agent_path(agent.id), class:"team-link" do %>
  .....
 <% end %> (all working, routes stable)
```

views/pages/show.html.erb:

```
<p><% @admin.name %>, with id <% @admin.id %></p>  
#rendering == $0
```

Where's the data connection breaking down? I've been working at this for a day or so now and this is a fairly solid wall for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, your ERB statements are a bit off. You need to use the `<%= %>` format for the output of your ruby code to be shown (note the `=`).

So `<% @admin.name %>` should be `<%= @admin.name %>`, etc.

Comment: Oh dang, that was exactly it. I was having a similar issue with another page, but only for part of the db since the rest of it was formatted properly. There's something to be said for fresh eyes.  Thanks!